# FreeBSD Kmod Cannot find sys/param.h

Tags: c, kernel, freebsd

I am reading FreeBSD Device Drivers book.
The first example is hello.c. But, When I am compiling it, it says hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sys/param.h' file not found

hello.c

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>

static int
hello_modevent(module_t mod __unused, int event, void *arg __unused)
{
    int error = 0;
    switch (event)
    {
        case MOD_LOAD:
            uprintf("Hello, world\n");
        case MOD_UNLOAD:
            uprintf("GoodBye, cruel world");
        default:
             error = EOPNETSUPP;
    }

return (error);
}

static moduledata_t hello_mod = {
   "hello",
   hello_modevent,
   NULL
}

DECLARE_MODULE(hello, hello_mod, SI_SUB_DRIVERS, SI_ORDER_MIDDLE);
```

Makefile

```
KMOD= hello
SRCS= hello.c

.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

uname -a
FreeBSD FreeBSD-1 10.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE #0 r260789: Fri Jan 17 01:46:25 UTC 2014     root@snap.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386

Thank you very much.
Add:

```
After I type make, the problem is
Warning: Object directory not changed from original /usr/home/user/Workplaces/hello
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror -D_KERNEL -DKLD_MODULE -nostdinc   -I. -I@ -I@/contrib/altq -fno-common   -mno-aes -mno-avx -mno-mmx -mno-sse -msoft-float -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -std=iso9899:1999 -Qunused-arguments -fstack-protector -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wcast-qual  -Wundef -Wno-pointer-sign -fformat-extensions  -Wmissing-include-dirs -fdiagnostics-show-option  -Wno-error-tautological-compare -Wno-error-empty-body  -Wno-error-parentheses-equality  -c hello.c
hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sys/param.h' file not found
#include <sys/param.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
*** Error code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't change any thing except recompiling the kernel. The problem has been settled, though I do not know the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the kernel source installed if you want to build modules.

Additionally, your code has some errors:

```
> make
Warning: Object directory not changed from original /home/rsmith/tmp/src/foo
cc -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Werror -D_KERNEL -DKLD_MODULE -nostdinc   -I. -I@ -I@/contrib/altq -fno-common  -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -mno-aes -mno-avx -mcmodel=kernel -mno-red-zone -mno-mmx -mno-sse -msoft-float  -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -ffreestanding -fstack-protector -std=iso9899:1999 -Qunused-arguments -fstack-protector -Wall -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Winline -Wcast-qual  -Wundef -Wno-pointer-sign -fformat-extensions  -Wmissing-include-dirs -fdiagnostics-show-option  -Wno-error-tautological-compare -Wno-error-empty-body  -Wno-error-parentheses-equality -c hello.c
hello.c:17:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EOPNETSUPP'
             error = EOPNETSUPP;
                     ^
hello.c:27:2: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
}
 ^
 ;
2 errors generated.
*** [hello.o] Error code 1
```

The constant `EOPNETSUPP` should be `EOPNOTSUPP` from `/usr/src/sys/sys/errno.h`.

The code should look like this:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>

static int
hello_modevent(module_t mod __unused, int event, void *arg __unused)
{
    int error = 0;
    switch (event)
    {
        case MOD_LOAD:
            uprintf("Hello, world\n");
        case MOD_UNLOAD:
            uprintf("GoodBye, cruel world");
        default:
             error = EOPNOTSUPP;
    }

return (error);
}

static moduledata_t hello_mod = {
   "hello",
   hello_modevent,
   NULL
};

DECLARE_MODULE(hello, hello_mod, SI_SUB_DRIVERS, SI_ORDER_MIDDLE);
```

This compiles fine on my machine, FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE amd64

Comment: Thank you for fixing my typo. actually, a
hello.c:1:10: fatal error: 'sys/param.h' file not found
#include <sys/param.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
*** Error code 1

Stop.

Comment: the problem is make cannot find my .h file. I am using FreeBSD 10 32bit.

Comment: @user1111073 Are you sure you have the FreeBSD source code installed? You need it to build modules. It should be in the directory `/usr/src`.